# Caching in Entity Framework Extended and Expression

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, caching, expression

I'm using the Entity Framework 5.0 and the expression is described in the recommendations  [Type member support in LINQ-to-Entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733039/type-member-support-in-linq-to-entities/7777949#7777949)

```
public static Expression <Func <Category , bool >> IsRootExpression
{
get
{
    return p => p!= null && !p.ParentId.HasValue;
}
}
```

Everything worked well until I began to use the caching from "Entity Framework Extended Library" https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended

Currently, when I use in a query my expression IsRootExpression, an cache not expires, either automatically or using tags and forced expiration.
The code with using caching but without using the expression works properly and returns the updated data.

How to use both caching and expression?

To test, use the following code:
Data are updated:

```
var rep = new CategoryRepository ();
var testRoot = rep.AllIncluding(it => it.Items)
.Where(it=> !it.ParentId.HasValue)
.FirstOrDefault();
testRoot.Title = "test root " + DateTime .Now.ToLongTimeString(); 
rep.Save();
var tag = "test_tag" ;
CacheManager .Current.Expire(tag);

var rootCached = rep.AllIncluding(it => it.Items)
    .Where(it => !it.ParentId.HasValue)
    .FromCache(tags: new[] { tag })
    .FirstOrDefault();

bool isOk = rootCached.Title == testRoot.Title;
```

An outdated version is loaded from the cache:

```
var rep = new CategoryRepository ();
var testRoot = rep.AllIncluding(it => it.Items)
    .Where( Category.IsRootExpression)
    .FirstOrDefault();
testRoot.Title = "test root " + DateTime .Now.ToLongTimeString();
rep.Save();
var tag = "test_tag" ;
CacheManager .Current.Expire(tag);

var rootCached = rep.AllIncluding(it => it.Items)
    .Where( Category.IsRootExpression)
    .FromCache(tags: new[] { tag })
    .FirstOrDefault();

bool isOk = rootCached.Title == testRoot.Title;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using an expression, it's part of the query and could also become part of a compiled query. That's where I see the link to caching.

If you define your method instead:

```
public static Func<Category,bool> IsRootSelector
{
   get { return p => p!= null && !p.ParentId.HasValue; }
}
```

You shouldn't experience any caching problems, like in your first example.