# How to efficiently use expressions to prevent Entity Framework from error The specified type member is not supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, linq-expressions

I want to delete entities that are older than some date and I want to do it in generic way. The reason is there are entities of several kinds, and they all have `ID` and `DateTime`. I use `ID` and `DateTime` to make queries and log them.

But I have this exception:
`Domain.DataAccessException: Removing old results failed ---> System.NotSupportedException: The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.`

Now, I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733039/type-member-support-in-linq-to-entities) that we have to create expression to make it clear for database how to treat these properties. I guess I can do it but expressions are costly to compile.

My question is what are the best practices to do generic things like this in Entity Framework? Is it good approach to compile the expression only once for each type of entity and then just use it without cost?

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int ID { get; }
    DateTime Date { get; }
}

public class DailyResult : IEntity { ... }

public void ClearDaily(DateTime cutoffPoint)
{
    CleanEntities<DailyResult>(cutoffPoint);
}    

private void CleanEntities<TEntity>(DateTime cutoffPoint) where TEntity : class, IEntity
{
    var set = context.Set<TEntity>().AsQueryable();

    var itemsToDelete = set.Where(x =>     DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Date).Value.CompareTo(cutoffPoint) == -1).ToArray();
    log.DebugFormat("Found {0} results", itemsToDelete.Length);
    if (itemsToDelete.Any())
    {
        var idsToDelete = string.Join(", ", itemsToDelete.Select(x =>     x.ID).ToArray());
        foreach (var entity in itemsToDelete)
        {
            MarkDelete(entity);
        }
        context.SaveChanges();

        log.InfoFormat("Removed records older than date {0}: {1}",     cutoffPoint.ToShortDateString(), idsToDelete);
    }
}

private bool MarkDelete<T>(T entity) where T : class
{
    context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    return context.SaveChanges() > 0;
}
```

Comment: DateTime was unsupported (not sure now) try using DateTimeOffset

Answer (score 0):

imho `TruncateTime(x.Date)` is evaluated as `x.Date.Date` which is not handled by linq to entities.

In your case you can use

```
cutoffPoint = cutoffPoint.Date;
var itemsToDelete = set.Where(x => x.Date < cutoffPoint).ToArray();
```

this does not answer to the primary question. For this you have integration test: test involving the "business" (where your queries reside) layer and the persistence layer. Or more precisely a test not involving mocking EF.

And/Or always test your query in linqpad or the same.